# Full screen issue after manually creating an empty application in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode6

Since xcode 6 didn't offer an empty application any more, I manually created one by deleting the `Launch screen interface file` and the `Main storyboard file base name` in the info.plist file, and deleted Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.xib then. Considering that I'll drawing the UI by myself, I created a view controller without an xib file. But when I ran the app, there are black bars both on the top and the bottom. I checked the `[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]` and found out that the bounds was 480*320.

I've checked on google and there were suggestions like adding png pictures or creating a xib file, but I really wonder why the property `bounds` didn't get the right size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have met with this problem, it's because you delete your "Launch screen file" and didn't set in general tab "Launch image source".
So you need to make .xcassets file, after right click inside .xcassets file you create "New Launch Image" with name something like "LaunchImage" and set images for appropriate sizes. After that in general tab you set "Launch image source" property name with your "LaunchImage".

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to keep the storyboard and everything else Xcode sets up for a single-view app, and then build out your UI programmaticly from the ViewController. That way, you inherit all the automagic stuff the SDK does during startup.

I can't tell you exactly what this automagic stuff is; but, I'm pretty sure your bug would go away if you adopted this approach.